# How to extract token value for authentication in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract a token values from the Response Data. I make use of Regular Expression Extractor to get `VIEWSTATE & EVENTVALIDATION` values, but I also need to get `'8579B772905C87F270BC7E7D648572A5AB55D1B7E7FB7EA2C33F8281125935EEE3D12D705E3ED1EBE59D4B66C90738FC11B087AD5D123DEAE5C29DD57218B107'` value from the below mentioned response:

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" class="login_N" onclick="

var pattern_Null = '^ *$';
var reg_Null = new RegExp(pattern_Null);

if(reg_Null.test(document.getElementById('txtUserId').value)){
    alert('Enter the Login Name');
    document.getElementById('txtUserId').focus();
    return false;
}

if(reg_Null.test(document.getElementById('txtPwd').value)){
    alert('Enter the Password');
    document.getElementById('txtPwd').focus();
    return false;
}

var s = document.getElementById('txtPwd').value;

document.getElementById('password').value = Encrypt(s,'8579B772905C87F270BC7E7D648572A5AB55D1B7E7FB7EA2C33F8281125935EEE3D12D705E3ED1EBE59D4B66C90738FC11B087AD5D123DEAE5C29DD57218B107','10001');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

> Encrypt(s, '([^']+?)')

Use $1$ in template field